# Почему не работает перевод произвольных строк polylang?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, polylang

перевожу строку, с помощью polylang. Делал по примерам в интернете. Что я делаю не так?
Вот так регистрирую строки:

```
add_action('init', 'truemisha_polylang_strings' );
 
function truemisha_polylang_strings() {
 
  if( ! function_exists( 'pll_register_string' ) ) {
    return;
  }
    
  
  pll_register_string(
    'welcome_message', // название строки
    'Уважаемые посетители сайта ТОО «КазМед Экспертиза»!
  Мы рады приветствовать Вас на нашем сайте.
  Здесь Вы получите всю необходимую информацию о нашей Компании.', // сама строка
    'main', // категория для удобства
    true // будут ли тут переносы строк в тексте или нет
  );
}
```

Появляются строки в string translations

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmEBa.png

Затем вот так вывожу в файле шаблона

```
<?php echo esc_attr( pll__( 'Уважаемые посетители сайта ТОО «КазМед Экспертиза»! Мы рады приветствовать Вас на нашем сайте. Здесь Вы получите всю необходимую информацию о нашей Компании.' ) ) ?>
```

Вот так вывел кнопки

```
<?php pll_the_languages(array('dropdown'=>1)); ?>
```

Но на сайте все равно текст не переводит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так как при регистрации строки вы выставили параметр `multiline => true`, то вам нужно передавать строку в функцию перевода в таком же форматировании как и при регистрации

```
<?php echo esc_attr( pll__( 'Уважаемые посетители сайта ТОО «КазМед Экспертиза»!
Мы рады приветствовать Вас на нашем сайте.
Здесь Вы получите всю необходимую информацию о нашей Компании.' ) ); ?>
```